# JSX expressions may not use the comma operator. Did you mean to write an array?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm getting this error

> JSX expressions may not use the comma operator. Did you mean to write an array?

on following code snippets where am getting this error

```
<Text style={[theme.interRegular14], { fontWeight: 'bold' }}>No products bookmarked</Text>
```

I'm new to this codebase but found this error but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: What value does `theme.interRegular14` have?  What resulting object are you expecting/intending to use in this `style` property?

Comment: What was the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use ***`,`***. Instead, you can try this:

```js
<Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold',...theme.interRegular14 }}>No products bookmarked</Text>
```

##### Explanation:

Let's say you have an object:

```
const theme = {
    interRegular14: {
      key1: "value1",
      key2: "value1"
    }
}
```

And when you use ***`theme.interRegular14`***. You get this following data:

```
{
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value1"
}
```

Now you can use this method to merge this object with new keys and values.

```
const newOBJ = {fontWeight: 'bold',...theme.interRegular14 }
```

Now this will return the final object as:

```
{
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value1"
}
```